# Is it possible to print a list of orders including items ordered?

Tags: magento2, orders, reports

I'd like to print a report that simply lists the orders made in the last month, that includes simple order info including price, customer name, etc, as well as the items in that order.  It seems that items orders/invoiced is not an option either in reporting or in the order list.  Is there a way to print a simple list of orders such as this?

Answer (score 0):

From `Sales->Orders` you can able to see the grid with the details. In that same grid you can add the extra column by choosing from here https://www.screencast.com/t/u9sb2w7XFmx .

In that columns section, we don't have product name details because if a order has more products then it is difficult to accommodate in the grid. But you can overwrite the grid file and add the product details in the collection.